# If Gson mapper is chosen, the oauth token response is empty

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth

When I set the property **spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson** in application.properties and add the gson dependency, the oauth token is not returned (the json returned is empty).
Setting the property to **spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=jackson** makes it work again.
We use Gson as main parser and we cannot move to Jackson, do you have an idea about this issue?

I created a project in Github for this issue (https://github.com/marcellom/sample-oauth2-spring-gson), you can clone it and follow the instructions in the README.

Dependencies:

- Spring Boot: 1.5.6.RELEASE
- Gson: 2.8.0
- spring-security-oauth2: 2.2.0.RELEASE

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Spring provides `OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Serializer` for `Jackson`, for `Gson` you must provide your own.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks chimmi! I solved it by adding a custom serializer for Gson.